# R: split column

Tags: r

I have a column (geneDesc) in a data frame (bacteria) that I want to split into two columns. The column contains the gene ID and the species name of the organism the gene comes from in brackets.

For example:

```
geneDesc
hypothetical protein, partial [Vibrio shilonii]
ankyrin repeat protein [Leptospira kirschneri]
helicase [Alteromonas macleodii]
```

I'm using the following command:

```
bacteria2 <- separate(bacteria, geneDesc, c("gene", "species"), sep = "\\[")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: Values not split into 2 pieces at 341, 342, 448, 450, etc...
```

Is there a way to run the command anyway and just create another column where there is another "["? Everything after the first bracket is of no interest.

Comment: Would you mind if you can show us your desired outcome? By reading the last line, it seems that you do not want things after the first `[`. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it but your `sep` regular expression needs adjusted to match either a `[` or `]`:

```
library(tidyr)
bacteria %>% separate(geneDesc,c("gene","species"), sep="[\\[\\]]", extra="drop")
```

Output:

```
                            gene               species
1 hypothetical protein, partial        Vibrio shilonii
2        ankyrin repeat protein  Leptospira kirschneri
3                      helicase  Alteromonas macleodii
```

Answer (score 0):

`separate(..., extra = "drop")`

or

`separate(..., extra = "merge")`

another option is

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
bacteria %>%
  mutate(gene = geneDesc %>% str_replace_all(" *\\[.*$", "") )
```

Comment: `separate` is not an R function, though. Maybe you can help the OP by editing the package (whatever it is) into their question?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove everything after the first bracket I suggest `gsub`

```
> df <- read.table(text='hypothetical protein, partial [Vibrio shilonii]
+ ankyrin repeat protein [Leptospira kirschneri]
+ helicase [Alteromonas macleodii]', sep='\n')

> df
                                               V1
1 hypothetical protein, partial [Vibrio shilonii]
2  ankyrin repeat protein [Leptospira kirschneri]
3                helicase [Alteromonas macleodii]

> gsub('\\s+\\[.*$', '', df$V1)
[1] "hypothetical protein, partial" "ankyrin repeat protein"        "helicase"                     

> data.frame(data=gsub('\\s+\\[.*$', '', df$V1))
                           data
1 hypothetical protein, partial
2        ankyrin repeat protein
3                      helicase
```