# How to transform the Margin column in two columns i.e. 1 for Runs and other for Wickets?

Tags: r

```
> head(ODI)


       Team.1       Team.2      Winner    Margin     Ground      Match.Date    

1 New Zealand       Pakistan New Zealand   61 runs     Wellington  06-Jan-18      

2 New Zealand       Pakistan New Zealand   8 wickets   Nelson      09-Jan-18      

3      U.A.E.       Ireland     Ireland   4 wickets   ICCA Dubai      11-Jan-18     

4 New Zealand       Pakistan New Zealand  183 runs    Dunedin                  13-Jan-18     

5      U.A.E.       Ireland     Ireland   67 runs ICCA Dubai      13-Jan-18     

6   Australia       England     England 5 wickets  Melbourne      14-Jan-18
```

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834538/r-split-column).

Answer (score 0):

```r
df['Win by runs'] = df['Margin'].apply(lambda x : re.sub("\D", "", x) if 'runs' in str(x) else 0)
df['Win by wickets'] = df['Margin'].apply(lambda x : re.sub("\D", "", x) if 'wickets' in str(x) else 0)
```